# What statistical test to use if I have one categorical dependent variable, 3 test periods and categorical groups within the test periods?

Tags: statistics, statistical-test

I have one dependent variable - payment made or payment not made. I have three different test periods (that include different people) and I want to know whether there are statistically significant differences between these different test periods and groups (like gender, age, etc).